# Answer login event from fabric crashlytics did not logging

Tags: swift, crashlytics, rx-swift, google-fabric

I am using `Answers` event logging from fabric. But sometimes it doesn't recorded as it should be in the fabric dashboard. Right now, i call the API from function that returns its weak reference. Is that matter?

```
return PINInteractor.registerWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: self.phoneNumber, PIN: self.PIN.value, authorizationCode: authorizationCode)
    .map { [weak self] _ -> PINSuccessModel in
        guard let `self` = self else {
            return PINSuccessModel()
        }

        Answers.logLogin(withMethod: "LOGIN FACEBOOK", success: true), customAttributes: nil)
        return PINSuccessModel()
    }
})
```

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. In your local testing, do you see the answers event being recoded in the Logcat output?

Also, if you hit the else case in your code, then the Answers event wouldn't trigger.

Comment: Hi, Mike! Thanks for reaching me out. I found no logcat output about Answer, and I am 100% sure that Answer was called (using breakpoint). Is there any ideas why?

Comment: Hmm, interesting that the breakpoint was hit, but no data was logged. Try enabling debug mode to get more info: final Fabric fabric = new Fabric.Builder(this)
        .kits(new Crashlytics())
        .debuggable(true)
        .build();
Fabric.with(fabric);

Comment: Is there any reference for swift?

Comment: It's so strange that it logged if I re-run the project from xcode. Is there any clue?